# How do I use one htaccess file to 301 urls from multiple domains to new urls on a new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I am trying to just use one htaccess file on one apache server. I have multiple domain names pointing at the ip address for the server where the htaccess file is located.

What I want to do is to use that one htaccess file to redirect various page URLs from the different domains to new URLs on a new domain.

This doesn't work, but it's where I got to, and hopefully explains further:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 old-domain1.com/url.html https://newsite.com/url-from-domain1.html
Redirect 301 old-domain2.com/url.html https://newsite.com/url-from-domain2.html
Redirect 301 old-domain3.com/url.html https://newsite.com/url-from-domain3.html
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for, and it works as expected.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect old-domain1.com/url.html to https://new-domain1.com/new-url.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^url\.html$ https://new-domain1.com/new-url.html [R=301,L]

# Redirect old-domain2.com/old-url.html to https://new-domain2.com/new-url.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^old-url\.html$ https://new-domain2.com/new-url.html [R=301,L]

# Redirect old-domain3.com/another-url.html to https://new-domain3.com/different-url.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain3\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^another-url\.html$ https://new-domain3.com/different-url.html [R=301,L]
```